# What would be an efficient design for this use case

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a use case where I am starting a timer on a particular method to see if it  takes more than x seconds . If so, I am logging a fatal in our logs as follows.

```
private boolean isDpxTimedOut(StopWatch stopWatch)
{
       stopWatch.stop();
       long elapsedTime = stopWatch.getNanoTime();
       Double elapsedTimeInSeconds = elapsedTime/NANO_DIVISOR;
       return (elapsedTimeInSeconds >= DPX_TIMEOUT_VALUE);
}
public void callDPX()
{
 try{
 StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
 //body of the method
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {  
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
  finally {
              //putting a check here to see if DPX timed out and then logging a FATAL.
           if(isDpxTimedOut(stopWatch))
           {
                  log.fatal("[DPX TIMEOUT] The request took more than 12 seconds.");
           }

}
```

Now I have a use case where I have to put this stoip watch on multiple methods in different classes. How should I design that?. The timeouts for different classes will be diffrent and should be read from a Config file. Can someone point me to a good design for this use case.

Comment: Why you just don't create a interface and implement it in your all class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
class Executor {
    public static void execAndLogOnTimeout(Runnable runnable, long timeout) {
        // Save start time
        runnable.run();
        // Save end time
        // If time taken > timeout: log
    }
}

Executor.execAndLogOnTimeout(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        // The code to be clocked
    }
}, Config.timeoutForThisPieceOfCode());
```

Another option would be to use AOP around advice.

Comment: If you need to customize the log message per code to be clocked, then pass that as an argument or create your own abstract class that implements Runnable and takes a message (or type) as a constructor argument.

Answer (score 0):

First change your isDpxTimedOut,  callDPX methods to take the time as argument so that you can pass it different numbers from the configuration file..

Design would be.. Create a base class and put your methods  there.. What ever classes you write extend that base class. Inside your class, if you want to call the timeout method, first get the respective time from configuration file and call callDPX() with time argument..

Answer (score 0):

In this case [Proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) can help you.

> A proxy is a well-used design pattern. To put it simply, a proxy is an object that looks like another object, but adds special functionality behind the scene.

It's better explained by [GOF - Design Pattern](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Proxy.aspx)

### The Proxy Pattern

> This is a structural pattern as it defines a manner for creating relationships between classes or entities. The proxy design pattern is used to provide a surrogate or placeholder object, which references an underlying object.
>
> Allows for object level access control by acting as a pass through entity or a placeholder object.

[Spring AOP](https://stackoverflow.com/) uses the same design pattern.

[learn more...](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-proxy)

Just wrap the object add new functionality before and after the actual object call.

[image]